# Is there a mathematical criteria to determine the number of positive eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Is there a mathematical criteria to determine the number of positive eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix? This is related to the stability problem of a special dynamical system.

Comment: The zeroes of the characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues. It should not be that hard to find out which of those are positive.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks. Is there a formal theorem/criteria to determine the number of positive eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Browsing the related posts that the bot found gives [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621633/the-number-of-positive-eigenvalues-of-a-non-singular-symmetric-matrix-is-equal-t?rq=1). I am not sure if that's what you are looking for. It seems like you are not asking for a numerical method. If that's the case I find the question strange. Zeroes of characteristic polynomial should be a formal enough criterion.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for your reply. My question is about the relationship between the property of symmetric matrix and the number of its  positive eigenvalues, instead of numerical method of finding zeros.

Comment: At least we know that a [positive definite symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) has only positive eigen values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific context, Descartes' rule of sign gives you an exact answer.

It will tell you that number of positive eigenvalues will be equal to the number of sign changes in the coefficients (omitting zero ones) of the characteristic polynomial. Note that this is not the case for general polynomials.

The issue here is that this criterion depends nonlinearly of the entries which may be complicated.

Comment: @Blue We are talking here of the characteristic polynomial of a real symmetric matrix which only has real eigenvalues. So, the gap, which is due to the existence of complex roots, does not arise in this context.

Comment: Ah, right ... "symmetric". Nevermind. :)

Comment: @KBS Thanks a lot for your comments. It is really helpful.